# О согласованном определении

Tags: пунктуация

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться!

"*Прибитая снегом трава лежала полосами*".

Почему нет запятой перед травой? Это же (как пить дать) согласованное определение перед главным словом с ДОЗ — *почему она лежала полосами? потому что её прибило снегом*, —  т.е. причинное значение.

Answer (score 1):

Не вижу причинного значения: так как трава прибита снегом, она лежала полосами. Это выглядит довольно странно, ведь она может лежать после заморозков не только полосами, но и сплошь. Она лежала полосами, потому что полосами шли заморозки, так бывает.

Answer (score 1):

[Арсеньев В. К. По уссурийскому краю](http://lib.com.ua/books/5/318n10.html)

**Почему трава лежала полосами**

Я поспешно вылез наружу и невольно закрыл глаза рукой. **Кругом все белело
от снега.** Воздух был свежий, прозрачный. Морозило. По небу плыли разорванные облака; кое-где виднелось синее небо. Хотя кругом было еще хмуро и сумрачно, но уже чувствовалось, что скоро выглянет солнце. **Прибитая снегом трава лежала полосами.** Дерсу собрал немного сухой ветоши, развел небольшой огонек и сушил на нем мои обутки. **Теперь я понял, почему Дерсу в некоторых местах не велел резать траву.** Он скрутил ее и при помощи ремней и веревок перетянул поверх шалаша, чтобы его не разметало ветром.

**Вывод:** причастный оборот "прибитая снегом" не обособляется, так как не имеет  причинного значения.

Для выявления дополнительного обстоятельственного значения желательно видеть полный текст.

Comment: егоне = его не?

Comment: Спасибо, исправлено.

Answer (score 0):

Здесь нельзя говорить об однозначно необходимой запятой, поскольку причастный оборот *предшествует* определяемому слову (запятая при этом **не требуется**, если это слово — не личное местоимение).
Тем не менее, через такую запятую **возможен** авторский акцент на причинности (= *будучи прибита снегом*), нужно только считаться с тем, вписывается ли это в общий контекст, поскольку трава начинает восприниматься почти как "лирический герой". Например, если перед этим были рассуждения о траве, которую сами посеяли и т. п., то такой акцент выглядит уместным.

[Обособление согласованных определений](http://www.gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_174)